# Pass Int by value to closure

Tags: swift, for-loop, closures

I have this code:

```
for var i = 0; i < self.blockViews.count; i++ {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
        // Some animation
        }, completion: {
            completion in
            // i is always blockViews.count as the for loop exits before completion closure is called
            if i == 0 {
                // Some completion handling
            }
    })
}
```

I am trying to use `i` inside my closure; is there a way to do this other than assigning it to a `let`, and then using it (pass by value)?

```
for var i = 0; i < self.blockViews.count; i++ {
    let copyOfI = i
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
        // Some animation
        }, completion: {
            completion in
            if copyOfI == 0 {
                // This works
            }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there's a way to achieve that, and it's called the **capture list**: you simply have to list the variables you want to capture as a comma separated list enclosed in square brackets - in your case, it's just `[i]`:

```
for var i = 0; i < self.blockViews.count; i++ {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
        // Some animation
        }, completion: {
            [i] completion in
         // ^^^ capture list is here
            // i is always blockViews.count as the for loop exits before completion closure is called
            if i == 0 {
                // Some completion handling
            }
            println(i)
    })
}
```

Reference: [Closure Expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID393)

**Old answer**

You can enclose the loop code in a closure and pass the index as a closure parameter:

```
for var i = 0; i < self.blockViews.count; i++ {
    { (index) in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
            // Some animation
            }, completion: {
                completion in
                // i is always blockViews.count as the for loop exits before completion closure is called
                if index == 0 {
                    // Some completion handling
                }
        })
    }(i)
}
```

Comment: Well that's also a solution :) I really hoped there was some kind of other somution to force pass by value

Comment: Cool, I had a strong feeling this was possible!

Answer (score 1):

You either have to create a copy using a let (like you have done in your question) or pass it into the closure through the closure's parameters.

Seeing as you're using a UIView.animateWithDuration closure, your best bet is assigning it to a let variable inside your closure.

Comment: Wow, I really expected there to be a way to pass it into a closure by value (like an `inout` parameter)

Comment: Well, you can, but if you're using the UIView.animateWithDuration function then it doesn't expect a closure with those type parameters. This would only work with your own functionand closure declarations